# Reject nested assosciation creation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models as below,

*Updated based on suggestions*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
  has_many :roles, through: :company_users
end
```

and

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :role

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_users
  validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:company, :role]}
end
```

I find the uniqueness validation is working only on the `update` request. On `create` request validation is not functioning and it simply bypasses it.

I want to enable the same validation to reject if a user has same company & role assigned more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue with the below validation,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
  has_many :roles, through: :company_users
  validate :company_users, :uniqueness_of_company_users
end

private

def uniqueness_of_company_users
  errors.add(:company_users, 'error in role creation') if company_users.map{|x| "#{x.company_id} #{x.role_id}"}.uniq.size != company_users.size
end
```

This is the additional validation required to solve the issue

Thanks Rich Peck for this [https://railscoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/uniqueness-gotcha/](http://link)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ensure the uniqueness of user on unique pair of :company and :role, then you can try following. By default, the validations run for both create and update. You don't need `:on => [ :create, :update ]`. So it should be just:

```
validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:company, :role]}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers)

> The :on option takes **one** of the values `:create` or `:update`

--

A validation is *only* run on `create` or `update` anyway, right?

`find` doesn't manipulate the db, `destroy` gets rid of the record & `new` just invokes a new instance of the object. You have literally zero other reasons to validate.

So, really, you should have:

```
validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:company_id, :role_id]}
```

This will look up against the values in `company_id` and `role_id`, which is probably going to be more efficient than calling the `company` and `role` objects themselves.

I could be wrong, but  I really think if you used the above, it should work.

--

You may also wish to clean up your models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
  has_many :roles, through: :company_users
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :role

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_users
  validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:company_id, :role_id]}
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have removed the `on => [:create, :update]` and yes, I agree, this should work ideally. But its not.  As per this [link](http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/) it says a validation on the nested attributes as well.

Comment: It just doesn't fire at all?

Comment: no, still `create` can fire with duplicated entries

Comment: And you're using `:company_id, :role_id` or `:company, :role`?

Comment: Something interesting https://railscoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/uniqueness-gotcha/

Comment: yes I am using `validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:company_id, :role_id]}`

Comment: Thanks for the link, let me check it out.. Close match :)